# Yaml numeric keys: can't start with zero?

Tags: twig, yaml

Let's say I have this `.yml` file used for Symfony2 i18n

```
month:
  01: Jan
  02: Feb
  03: Mar
  04: Apr
  05: May
  06: Jun
  07: Jul
  08: Aug
  09: Sep
  10: Oct
  11: Nov
  12: Dec
```

In twig, for tanslation, I will use something like

```
{% set month = my_date|date("m") %}
{{ ('month.'month)|trans }}
```

In this scenario, all months starting with "0" will not be translated. I've read yaml documentation (not so deep, but I've searched on the internet) and I haven't find any page saying that a key couldn't start with zero (and it seems not to be possible for a key start with zero).

### So, my questions are:

- Is that a yaml issue?
- If this isn't an issue, why keys could not start with "0"?

Comment: Did you try with quotes like `"01": Jan`? I bet php is trying to interpret 01, becoming a 1.

Comment: @Maerlyn: you were right, please write and answer and let me accept it :) Thank You.

Comment: Just accept @AlainTiemblo 's answer, that's the same as my suggestion, I see no point in duplicating it. I'm here to help, not for the rep :)

Comment: @Maerlyn: Oh, of course, but I've asked to you just for fairness. If you don't care, ok, I'll accept his answer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Maerlyn commeted, you should encapsulate your keys with quotes to avoid loosing preceding and following zeros.

[image]